Project landing page (freecodecamp) pricing design
I am working on building a project landing page from freecodecamp learning site. I have to design the following part

Now, following is my HTML and CSS code for this part.


.price-tag {
    background-color: antiquewhite;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0.5em 2em 0.5em 2em;
}

button {
    padding: 0.8em 1.1em;
    background-color:coral;
    border: none;
    font-size: 1em;
}

button:hover {
    background-color: aqua;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.price-category {
    background-color: aqua;
    width: 100%;
}

.price {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: 700;
}
<div class="price-tag">
        <div class="price-category">
            <h3 >TENOR TROMBONE</h3>
        </div>

        <p class="price">$600</p>

        <div>
            <p>Lorem ipsum.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum.</p>
        </div>

        <button type="button">SELECT</button>
</div>



I am close but don't quite get the complete part. The background color for TENOR TROMBONE doesn't take the entire width of the container. Also, the text below is left aligned instead of center aligned. I have used flexbox to arrange the items. How can I improve this ?
Thanks

The issues you are encountering are because of two things:

You have not specifically defined the alignment of your header (h3) inside your price-category div
You have added padding (padding: 0.5em 2em 0.5em 2em;) to your container div.

Amending these two issues, you can see that the output is what you desire.


.price-tag {
    background-color: antiquewhite;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

button {
    padding: 0.8em 1.1em;
    background-color: coral;
    border: none;
    font-size: 1em;
}

button:hover {
    background-color: aqua;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.price-category {
    background-color: aqua;
    width: 100%;
}

.price-category > h3 {
  text-align: center;
}

.price {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: 700;
}
<div class="price-tag">
        <div class="price-category">
            <h3 >TENOR TROMBONE</h3>
        </div>

        <p class="price">$600</p>

        <div>
            <p>Lorem ipsum.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum.</p>
        </div>

        <button type="button">SELECT</button>
</div>




it works. But I want to understand why padding was affecting it.

@user9026 - You added padding to your entire layout so it prevented the inner elements to stretch to your desired width. I can suggest reading more about padding here
